# Function still running although the condition is not met

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function below called `daterange` once the condition met and it executed, it keeps running even if param value is not equal to "date".

I've also tried to use return to exit from the function but it's still running.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
    var concept = $(this).text();
    $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
    $('[id$=hdnSearchParam]').val(param);
    if (param == "date") {
      $(function daterange() {
        $("#<%= txtsearch.ClientID %>").daterangepicker({
          locale: {
            format: 'DD/MMM/YYYY'
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      return false;
    }

  });
});

//Re-Create for on page postbacks
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function daterange() {
  $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
    var concept = $(this).text();
    $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
    $('[id$=hdnSearchParam]').val(param);
    if (param == "date") {
      $(function() {
        $("#<%= txtsearch.ClientID %>").daterangepicker({
          locale: {
            format: 'DD/MMM/YYYY'
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Provide a demo that replicates problem. Maybe you need to destroy the datepicker? Also...no need to wrap `$(function() {})` around plugin initialize within event handler.

Comment: how can i destroy it

Comment: Still not sure what exact problem is. Is it that selecting date then selecting something else leaves datepicker behind? Does datepicker being used have a destroy method? Not sure what plugin  is being used

Comment: "selecting date then selecting something else leaves datepicker" yes it  leaves datepicker running it must not run when i am selecting other values

Comment: Provide a demo in jsfiddle.net or plnkr.co as well as link to plugin docs

Answer (score 0):

i think it's better to isolate the initialization of the daterangepicker in a separate function like so

```
function initDateRange()
{
    $("#<%= txtsearch.ClientID %>").daterangepicker({
      locale: { format: 'DD/MMM/YYYY' }
    });
}
```

and call it

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
    var concept = $(this).text();
    $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
    $('[id$=hdnSearchParam]').val(param);
    if (param == "date") {
        initDateRange();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  });
});

//Re-Create for on page postbacks
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function daterange() {
$('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
    var concept = $(this).text();
    $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
    $('[id$=hdnSearchParam]').val(param);
       if (param == "date") {
           initDateRange();
    } else {
     return false;
  }
});
```